# bootstrap modal popup is not display from code behind?Only shadow is display

Tags: c#, bootstrap-modal

what is the reason the modal popup not displayed  from code behind when I want to call it after successful submission of data, for display success message.But only shadow is display not the full modal

Following is my html code

```
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body ">
                        <label style="color: green">
                            Your data is saved successfully.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The c# code for calling a modal is as follows

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", " $('#popup3').modal('show');", true);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "$('#popup3').modal('show');", true);
```

or

```
this.RegisterStartupScript("clentscript", "<script>$('#popup3').modal('show');</script>");
```

Comment: yes i use update panel. I tried without update panel also but no luck

Comment: there also  a control used to do so.  html part `<asp:Literal ID="LiteralText" runat="server" Text="This is example of Literal"></asp:Literal>`
and code part 
`Literal1.Text = @"<script>$(function(){$('#popup3').modal('show');});</script>";`

Comment: sir try to understand my question ,the modal is called but not display properly i.e. it only shows shadow

Comment: Then the style is issue not the code I suggest you to change your question then.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create modal in updatepanel with any input you need (textbox)

```html
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Open Modal" ID="button1" OnClick="button1_click"/>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header"></div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

2. On click, update your modal panel and register script

```js
protected void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  txtBox.Text = "update text";
  updatePanel1.Update();
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(updatePanel1, this.GetType(), "script", " $('#exampleModal').modal('show');", true);
}
```